# Java ArrayList<String>, getting a character in element 0

Tags: java, arrays

if I had a list like:

```
ArrayList<String> collection = new ArrayList<>();
```

Which gave elements `1` and `2`:

```
"(, element1", "), element2"
```

How do I extract the string from element1 and replace `'('` with a character of my choice?

I've tried to convert the `ArrayList<>` to a `String[]` but with no luck in getting individual String sets. I've also tried getting the element in the `ArrayList` such as `arrayList.get(0).contains("(")`. This is true or false depending on if the array contains an `'('`. Problem with that is that if it is true, what do I do to collect it and replace it? Doing `.get(0)` doesn't let me select a character in the string.

Comment: Please edit your question and include (1) what you've tried and (2) how what you tried didn't solve your problem.

Comment: Updated for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming "collection" already exists and has a `size()` of at least 1:

```
char charOfMyChoice = 'A';
String oldItem = collection.get(0);  
String newItem = oldItem.replaceFirst('(', charOfMyChoice); 
collection.set(0, newItem);
```

If instead you want to replace all occurances of '(', use the `replace()` or `replaceAll()` method instead of `replaceFirst()`.

Getting familiar with the [java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is essential to being comfortable in java.

Comment: Is it possible to edit the code to also get an element between two commas?

Comment: String s = "123,456,789", to extract 123, 456, or 789?

Comment: Yes, but you should ask a new question for a new answer. For that question, the method split in the String class would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> collection = new ArrayList<>();
        collection.add("(, element1\", \")");
        collection.add("element2");

        int index = 0;
        for(String s : collection) {
            if(s.contains("(")) {
                collection.set(index, s.replace("(", "["));
            }

            index++;
        }
        System.out.println(collection);
    }
}
```

Output:

> [[, element1", "), element2]

If you want to do it in the "modern" way, use streams:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> collection = new ArrayList<>();
        collection.add("(, element1\", \")");
        collection.add("element2");

        collection = (ArrayList<String>) 
            collection.stream()
                .map(str -> 
                    str.contains("(")? 
                            str.replace("(","[") :
                            str)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(collection);
    }
}
```

Output:

> [[, element1", "), element2]